# PHP Includes interpreted fine on WAMP but ignored on remote server

Tags: php, include, wamp

I have a static HTML header and footer included site wide via php include (php/navigation) and (php/footer.php) respectively.

The page interprets and includes all the of the above on WAMP with no errors (with either include or require) but when moved to my (LAMP) server the header and footer files are ignored (if i use require -- page displays nothing, so I know there is an error but I haven't been able to track it down)

other php includes in between the header and footer includes are read and displayed correctly and if i cut the the navigation.php and add it in place of the include it renders correctly -- but obviously i would rather avoid this approach.

Comment: Paths on windows are not case sensitive, but they are on Linux. I would bet money on this being your problem.

Comment: Show us these includes lines in your question. It is probably something among the line of "/dir/file.php" when you should "dir/file.php"

Comment: "dynamic static" is it dynamic or static?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: Should read header is static HTML echo'd in php '<?php include '/php/navigation.php';?>' and the file name is base/php/navigation.php (all lowercase) index file calling navigation is base/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the full file path. At the top of your file put this:

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__ . '/', TRUE);
```

Then when you want to call a file use:

```
include ROOT . 'path/to/file.php';
```

See if that helps.

Comment: thanks @Styphon -- this was my issue exactly; though I don't understand exactly why this fixes it